# Unresolved external symbol when using Boost.Log in Visual Studio with vcpkg

Tags: visual-studio, boost, visual-studio-2022, vcpkg, boost-log

I want to use Boost.Log in a solution with a DLL and an application consuming the DLL. I am using Visual Studio 2022 and vcpkg. I am **not** using CMake.

```cpp
// === DLL Project: ===
// Logger.hpp
#pragma once

#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK 1

#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/severity_channel_logger.hpp>

enum Severity {
    kFatal,
    kError,
    kWarning,
    kInfo,
    kTrace
};

BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(gLogger, boost::log::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<Severity>)

#define LOG_ERROR(...) BOOST_LOG_SEV(gLogger::get(), Severity::kError) << std::format(##__VA_ARGS__)

// Logger.cpp
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(gLogger, boost::log::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt) {
    boost::log::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<Severity> lg;
    return lg;
}

// === Application: ===
// Application.cpp
#include "Logger.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    try {
        prcd::Application app{};
        app.Run();
        return 0;
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        LOG_ERROR("{}", e.what());
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I am using vcpkg, my `vcpkg.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/vcpkg/master/scripts/vcpkg.schema.json",
  "name": "example",
  "version-string": "alpha",
  "dependencies": [
    {
      "name": "boost-log",
      "version>=": "1.79.0"
    }
  ],
  "builtin-baseline": "3d8f78171a2a37d461077bf8d063256b63e25a4f"
}
```

When I try to compile the project I get many unresolved external symbol errors:

```
1>Logger.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void * __cdecl boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??2impl@attribute@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@SAPEAX_K@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attributes::mutable_constant<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,void,void,void>::mutable_constant<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,void,void,void>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &&)" (??0?$mutable_constant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XXX@attributes@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@QEAA@$$QEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>Logger.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static void __cdecl boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attribute::impl::operator delete(void *,unsigned __int64)" (__imp_??3impl@attribute@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@SAXPEAX_K@Z) referenced in function "int `public: __cdecl boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attributes::mutable_constant<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,void,void,void>::mutable_constant<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,void,void,void>(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &&)'::`1'::dtor$0" (?dtor$0@?0???0?$mutable_constant@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XXX@attributes@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@QEAA@$$QEAV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z@4HA)
1>Logger.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attribute_set::attribute_set(void)" (__imp_??0attribute_set@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::basic_logger<char,class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<enum prcd::log::Severity,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,struct boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::multi_thread_model<class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::basic_logger<char,class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<enum prcd::log::Severity,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,struct boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::multi_thread_model<class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::aux::light_rw_mutex> >(void)" (??0?$basic_logger@DV?$severity_channel_logger_mt@W4Severity@log@prcd@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@sources@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@U?$multi_thread_model@Vlight_rw_mutex@aux@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@@2345@@sources@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@QEAA@XZ)
1>Logger.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct std::pair<class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attribute_set::iter<0>,bool> __cdecl boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attribute_set::insert(class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attribute_name,class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attribute const &)" (__imp_?insert@attribute_set@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@QEAA?AU?$pair@V?$iter@$0A@@attribute_set@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@_N@std@@Vattribute_name@234@AEBVattribute@234@@Z) referenced in function "protected: struct std::pair<class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attribute_set::iter<0>,bool> __cdecl boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::basic_logger<char,class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<enum prcd::log::Severity,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,struct boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::multi_thread_model<class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::add_attribute_unlocked(class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attribute_name const &,class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::attribute const &)" (?add_attribute_unlocked@?$basic_logger@DV?$severity_channel_logger_mt@W4Severity@log@prcd@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@sources@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@U?$multi_thread_model@Vlight_rw_mutex@aux@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@@2345@@sources@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@IEAA?AU?$pair@V?$iter@$0A@@attribute_set@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@_N@std@@AEBVattribute_name@345@AEBVattribute@345@@Z)
1>Logger.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: static class boost::shared_ptr<class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::core> __cdecl boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::core::get(void)" (__imp_?get@core@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@SA?AV?$shared_ptr@Vcore@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@@4@XZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::basic_logger<char,class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<enum prcd::log::Severity,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,struct boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::multi_thread_model<class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::basic_logger<char,class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::severity_channel_logger_mt<enum prcd::log::Severity,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,struct boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::sources::multi_thread_model<class boost::log::v2_mt_nt62::aux::light_rw_mutex> >(void)" (??0?$basic_logger@DV?$severity_channel_logger_mt@W4Severity@log@prcd@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@sources@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@U?$multi_thread_model@Vlight_rw_mutex@aux@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@@2345@@sources@v2_mt_nt62@log@boost@@QEAA@XZ)
```

I suspect I need to tell the linker where to find the libs for Boost.Log but I'm not sure how. For other libraries it "just works" with the setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason was that vcpkg builds boost for Win 7 and up. You need to `#define BOOST_USE_WINAPI_VERSION BOOST_WINAPI_VERSION_WIN7`, and everything works as expected.